# Button callback function not completely executed by Panel library in Python

Tags: python, callback, panel, dashboard

I am currently struggling trying to use the panel library in Python, in order to build an interactive dashboard to analyze and display CSV data. My current goal is to let the user enter an initial and a final date, which will be used to filter a DataFrame once a button is pressed. However, whenever I press the button, the on_click function is not completely executed before the script stops running. The code snippet is the following:

```
import panel as pn
pn.extension()

def acquire_data(dateBeginning, dateEnd):
    eventDF = pd.read_csv('multi.csv')
    eventDF['Date']= pd.to_datetime(eventDF['Date'])
    dateDF = eventDF[eventDF.upvotes > 8]
    print(eventDF)

def register_dates(event, save=True): 
    dateBeginning = date1Picker.value
    dateEnd = date2Picker.value
    
    if dateBeginning < dateEnd:
        text = pn.widgets.StaticText(name='Static Text', value='A string')
        spinner = pn.indicators.LoadingSpinner(width=50, height=50, value=True, color='info', bgcolor='light')
        layout = pn.Column(text, spinner, align='center')
        layout.app()
        print('getting in')
        acquire_data(dateBeginning, dateEnd)
        print('getting out')
        spinner.value = False
    else:
        print('Not working')
        #pn.pane.Alert('## Alert\nThis is a warning!')
    return save
     
date1Picker = pn.widgets.DatePicker(name='Date Initiale', margin=25)
date2Picker = pn.widgets.DatePicker(name='Date Finale', margin=25)
button = pn.widgets.Button(name="Analyse", button_type='primary', margin=(25, 0, 20, 200), width=200)
button.on_click(register_dates)

dateLayout = pn.Row(date1Picker, date2Picker)
layout = pn.Column(dateLayout, button, width=200, align='center')
layout.app()
```

I was also aiming at having the first layout be replaced by the one with the spinner and the text once the button is pressed, but I haven't found anything in the doc mentioning how to do so. If anyone could give me a hint regarding these issues, that would really help me!

Answer (score 0):

In **def acquire_data(dateBeginning, dateEnd):**
**pd**.read_csv('multi.csv'), **pd**.to_datetime(eventDF['Date'])

For start, in this function I think you forgot to **import panda** and your app just crash.

add: import pandas as pd

Ex:
import panel as pn
import pandas as pd

Comment: Oops sorry, forgot to mention that I am importing pandas in a previous cell. From what I noticed by running this notebook, the app manages to get up to the read_csv command, but abruptly stops right after it.